# Devops Sprint board shows remaining hours in Closed state - how do I eliminate?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a sprint board where the closed column shows up having a 2h remaining estimate - but the work items there are closed, so no work should remain - looked at all of the items there and none had any remaining time to show - how can I get a realistic value here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of work item which still display remaining hours after closed is **Bug**, then remaining hours will not be automatically cleared.

We clear the remaining hours for Tasks when the work item is Closed. However, bugs are slightly different because you have more flexibility with how you work with bugs and therefore we do not clear the remaining hours for the Bug work item type without a change to the process. Depending on whether you are an on-premises customer or not, you can add a rule to the Bug work item type to clear Remaining Hours. For details please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) and [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/90633/remaining-of-bugs-is-not-cleared-on-close.html).

If you are a cloud user, you could try adding this rule in organization setting -> Boards/Process -> Select the process you need to customize -> Select the work item type to add the rule -> Rules -> add "clear the value of Remaining Work" rule.
[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am a cloud user :)

Comment: It kind of helps - I would like it to be a project specific thing, as well as work item type related, but that does not seem possible currently - you explanation clarifies the issue though :)